# Angular - directive append loading indicator only to focused button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I took over an existing project and to get familiar with it I should add loading indicator for Export to file buttons.

I found out there's already a directive for that but in order to determinate on which button it should display loading it gets an input parameter passed in HTML.

```html
<button
  mat-stroked-button
  color="primary"
  [isLoading]="vm.isExporting && vm.exportType === exportType.XML"
  (click)="exportToXML()"
>...
</button>
```

That information is lost somewhere in the View Model and I thought it might be actually better to omit it and just show the spinner on the focused button.

So I did something like this and it kind of works:

```typescript
private showLoader(): void {
  // this.elemNative = el.nativeElement as HTMLElement (set in constructor)
  if (this.elemNative.classList.contains('cdk-focused')) {
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elemNative, this.loader);
    // this.loader is DIV created with renderer with spinner class
  }    
}
```

Problem is that for some reason `cdk-focused` and `cdk-mouse-focused` classes are not removed after the button loses the focus. As a workaround I'm getting rid of them in `hideLoader()` function using `renderer.removeClass(...)` but I believe there must be a better way. Any ideas?